# How to resolve the 400 error for a request token in OAuth Call

Tags: java, oauth, linkedin-api

I want to obtain an access token for my application using OAUth code it just acquired .This is my code i have done so far

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("https")
    .setHost("www.linkedin.com")
    .setPath("/uas/oauth2/accessToken")
    .setParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code")
    .setParameter("code", code)
    .setParameter("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:9090/ConnectSocialMedia/callBack.jsp")
    .setParameter("client_id", CONSUMER_KEY_OPTION)
    .setParameter("client_secret", CONSUMER_SECRET_OPTION)
    .build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponse response2 = client.execute(post);
System.out.println("Final Response------------>"+response2);
```

But each time i am getting HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request each time.Can anyone help where i am doing wrong .Thanks in advance

Comment: You have registered the callback corectly? You have made a request to "authorize" first to get an authoraziation code for exchange with access token?

Comment: did not get you properly ..is there anything wrong in my code ??

Comment: I can't see one. Its a http request as described in the linkedin oauth2 docu for code to access token exchange. So thats why I'm asking about the pre requirements.

Comment: Yes i am getting the authorization code .when the user is allowing access to my app created on developer.linkedin.com. and  i am forwarding this authorization code with other parameters to obtain access token but i am getting http 400 bad request